# next js 13 dev mode 100% CPU and RAM

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I’m trying to make an application based on Next.js 13. In the first few days, everything worked fine until I found out that my PC became slower. So I opened the task manager to see what was happening and found that the CPU was around 100% and the RAM was 100% or 98% (I have an i7 8th Gen and 12 GB RAM). The VSCode itself takes around 8GB of RAM. I only added two packages, the react-youtube and react-icons packages, and the application is still without the logic part, meaning it is only static pages. I don’t know if this problem is due to Next.js 13 or if there is anything that I can do to solve this problem.

I tried to create a new project and inspect the resource usage from the beginning of the project. I began adding the components and pages one by one, and I noticed that the resource usage got bigger and bigger until my PC got stuck on 100% CPU and RAM usage.
But the same application runs smoothly and fast when I run “npm run build” and then “npm run start”. In dev mode, everything is a pain for me.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is very simple I just delete the react-icons package my application become very fast and the lack of RAM and CPU usage is solved